# Strange problem when Using REGEX in my nodeJs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a doc which is a message in microsoft graph db and i am trying to parse some token / tracking nbr from the body. So in my case i get the info and then i pass the body to my regex function. And there is my problem, when i use

```
const str =  messages.value[0].body
console.log(str)
// check if we have a tracking id in the body
const trackingId = regex.getTrackingId(str)
if(trackingId){
  console.log('We have a Tracking ID ' + trackingId)
   }
```

it fails here is my getTrackingId function

```
function getTrackingId(body) {

try {

    console.log(body)
 const regex = /http:\/\/demo.example.com\/campaign\/(.+)\/tracker.png/gm;
 while ((m = regex.exec(body)) !== null) {
   // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
      regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  console.log(m)

if (m.length == 2) {
  return  m[1]
} else {
  return null
}
 }
} catch (error) {
console.log(error) }}
```

i made sure the text is past to the function and thats the case. if i take the body and make it static it works so realy not sure whats going on ?

```js
const str = `{ contentType: 'html',
  content:
   '<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">\r\n<meta content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<p>This is a Test Email which will be deleted</p>\r\n<img src="http://demo.example.com/campaign/xHMmLOSEpv/tracker.png">\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n' }
"`;

function getTrackingId(body) {
      try {
      

     const regex = /http:\/\/demo.example.com\/campaign\/(.+)\/tracker.png/gm;
     while ((m = regex.exec(body)) !== null) {
      // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
      if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
          regex.lastIndex++;
      }
    
    if (m.length == 2) {
      console.log('Tracking Nbr : ' + m[1])
    } else {
      console.log('No Tracking Nbr')
    }
     }
} catch (error) {
console.log(error)
}
}

getTrackingId(str)
```

Comment: Just to make sure: if you remove the `g` flag, does it work now? `const regex = /http:\/\/demo.example.com\/campaign\/(.+)\/tracker\.png/;`?

Comment: Nope it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

After digging a little deeper i found the issue. My RegEx code is fine. The problem is that when i get the response from Microsoft API and assign it to the str variable it sees it as an object. Since Regex does not like that it never matches anything.

So the simple fix was to to

```
const str =  JSON.stringify(messages.value[0].body)
```

i got to it when i tried to do a simple indexOf on str and got errors.